# Create a sub-list in r

Tags: r, list

I have this dataframe:

```
     x   y freq  E
1   10  15  100  6
2   20  25  100  5
3   30  35  100  1
4   40  45  100 23
5   50  55  100 11
6   60  65  100 13
7   70  75  100 27
8   80  85  100 30
9   90  95  100 15
10 100 105  100 28
```

From this, i want to create a list, and each member has to contain from 90% to 80% of the rows data, chosen randomly ( with `sample_n` i think).

I want something like this (in this example below, the choice isn't randomly for simplicity):

```
$`90%`
   a  b  E freq
1 10 15  6  100
2 20 25  5  100
3 30 35  1  100
4 40 45 23  100
5 50 55 11  100
6 60 65 13  100
7 70 75 27  100
8 80 85 30  100
9 90 95 15  100

$`80%`
   a  b  E freq
1 10 15  6  100
2 20 25  5  100
3 30 35  1  100
4 40 45 23  100
5 50 55 11  100
6 60 65 13  100
7 70 75 27  100
8 80 85 30  100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
list("80%" = sample_frac(df, .8), "90%" = sample_frac(df, .9))
```

(assuming your data frame is called df)

```
$`80%`
     x   y freq  E
7   70  75  100 27
8   80  85  100 30
9   90  95  100 15
3   30  35  100  1
10 100 105  100 28
5   50  55  100 11
6   60  65  100 13
1   10  15  100  6

$`90%`
     x   y freq  E
3   30  35  100  1
6   60  65  100 13
8   80  85  100 30
1   10  15  100  6
9   90  95  100 15
7   70  75  100 27
10 100 105  100 28
4   40  45  100 23
5   50  55  100 11
```

As suggested by Cath you can use `sapply` with `seq` to create a list of data frames ranging from 90 to 10 %:

```
sapply(seq(0.9, 0.1, -0.1), 
       function(pct) {df[sample(1:nrow(df), round(pct*nrow(df)), replace=FALSE), ]}, 
       simplify=FALSE)
```

If you want to use `sample_frac` you can modify her code like so:

```
sapply(seq(0.9, 0.1, -0.1), 
       function(pct) {sample_frac(df, pct)}, 
       simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: or something like `sapply(c("90%", "80%"), function(pct) {df[sample(1:nrow(df), round(as.numeric(substr(pct, 1, 2))/100*nrow(df)), replace=FALSE), ]}, simplify=FALSE)`

Comment: @beetroot thanks! it's ok... now if i wanted to include from 90% to 10% (90%,80%,70%,..... 10%)... there is something more compact to write that?

Comment: I can't think of a way right now, but maybe the suggestion by @Cath can be modified accordingly

Comment: you can try `sapply(paste0(seq(90, 10, -10), "%"), function(pct) {df[sample(1:nrow(df), round(as.numeric(substr(pct, 1, 2))/100*nrow(df)), replace=FALSE), ]}, simplify=FALSE)` or similar with `sample_frac`. the `paste0...` step is only for the names so something with `seq(0.9, 0.1, -0.1)` and then avoiding `substr` can be simpler

Comment: `sapply(seq(0.9, 0.1, -0.1), function(pct) {df[sample(1:nrow(df), round(pct*nrow(df)), replace=FALSE), ]}, simplify=FALSE)` should work (or accordingly with `sample_frac`

Comment: @Cath why not post as an answer? yours is clearly better and then Lince202 can accept your answer :)

Comment: no need for a second answer but feel free to edit your answer with a `sapply` way ;-)

Comment: @Cath perfect!!! now i have a little problem... suppose that i have a bigger data with different values of freq (for example 100,200,300)... so 10 rows for each value of freq... 
i want that the code runs for each freq...
for example...for percentage 90% i want 9 rows chosen randomly among the ten freq(100) rows, 9 rows for freq(200) and 9 rows for freq(300), etc.
How can be modify the code?